# Xdebug DBGp proxy does not de-register

Tags: proxy, xdebug, vscode-debugger, multi-user

1. I managed to setup `DBGp proxy` and was able to debug some code using the Linux binary here https://xdebug.org/files/binaries/dbgpProxy
2. I'm using Felix Becker's `PHP Debug` for VSCode as a client
3. If I start `PHP Debug` (which registers my IDE key with `DBGp proxy`) and shutdown VSCode without stopping `PHP Debug` first, it does not de-register with `DBGp proxy`
4. As a result, I can't start `PHP Debug` again because `DBGp proxy` reports that the IDE key was already registered and I have to restart the `DBGp proxy` each time this happens
5. I'm hoping there is a way to solve this at the `DBGp proxy` side. I mean, there can be a lot of other reasons why the client did not de-register
6. The less preferred alternative would be to get `PHP Debug` to listen even if registration failed, but that's a bit hacky in my opinion
7. Any ideas?

Thank you.